# What is difference between redux-persist and AsyncStorage?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-persist

Are they the same or not, what is difference, can't understand?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`redux-persist` is a Redux library that can be used to store and rehydrate your redux store [in a lot of different storage engines](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#storage-engines).

`AsyncStorage` is just one of these storage engines, and is the React Native equivalent to `LocalStorage` on the web, except that it is asynchronous.